# The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction

Tags: 2013-sp1

since some days ago I have the next issue when I make Update Preview on XPM.

[image]

[image]

```
 JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error 'The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.'
The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
Transaction Timeout
  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 2049 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction, Guid promoterType)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Guid promoterType)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.GetConnection()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDataSession..ctor()
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
eval code: Line 1 - Error: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.

   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator.EvaluateToObject(String statement)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator.EvaluateToString(String statement)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Package.EvaluateExpression(String expression)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformValueReferences(Package package, StringReference templateReference, Regex startTagExpression, String endTag)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformRegions(Package package, String dreamweaverTemplate)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformRepeatingRegions(Package package, StringReference templateReference)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.TransformRegions(Package package, String dreamweaverTemplate)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Dreamweaver.DreamweaverMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderContext context)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
   at SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I noticed If I changed a litle component it works fine, I think it could be a Time Out. Somebody has ever had this error?

Thanks

Comment: Ye, it sounds like a timeout. Do you see any corresponding error in event log or oData webservice log? May be that will reveal which part of tridion( GUI or Core service) is exactly timing out? I hope your database maintenance is up-to-date.

Comment: Yes I have seen the error in Event Viewer, I will update this post with an image. Do you know how can I increase the time out of Update Preview?Thanks!

Comment: There are a number of Timeout settings available for you to try and modify to see if they resolve your issue. 
These can be found at the following SDL Tridion KnowledgeBase link: 

http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/kb/article?ArticleId=4906&source=Article&c=12&cid=19 

(Note: Theses entries were first mentioned for SDL Tridion 2011 - However with the exception of the 'TcmNetTcpBinding' entry they still also apply for SDL Tridion 2013)

Comment: Thanks! it seems resolve the issue. Before write here i was changed TimeOut of MSDTC and cd_storage_conf of my application and cd_webservice_preview. But I think the last option of your link was the solution: In Tridion\bin\TcmServiceHost.exe.config,, add the following before </behaviour>
<serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:30:00" />

Comment: If you set your comment as a Solution I will validate as correct.Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear that issue resolved now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of timeout settings available for you to try and modify to see if they resolve your issue. These can be found at the following SDL Tridion KnowledgeBase [link](http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/kb/article?ArticleId=4906&source=Article&c=12&cid=19).

(Note: Theses entries were first mentioned for SDL Tridion 2011 - However with the exception of the 'TcmNetTcpBinding' entry they still also apply for SDL Tridion 2013SP1)